My while-loop isn't working, can't understand how to fix it
I have a loop that looks like this:
c_or_nc=input('Do you want to continue? (Yes/No): ')

if c_or_nc==('Yes'):
    continue_=True
if c_or_nc==('No'):
    continue_=False

while continue_ is True:
    n1 = float(input('Please, enter a number: '))
    op=input('Enter an operator (+, -, *, /, ^): ')
    n2=float(input('Enter a second number: '))
    print('The result is: '+str(result))
    c_or_nc=input('Do you want to continue? (Yes/No): ')
while continue_ is False:
    print('Alright! Have a nice day :).')

The output is what I want it to be if the answer is 'No' the first time and the loop doesn't start. After that, whatever the answer is, the loop continues.
I think if the answer is 'Yes' the first time, continue_ becomes True, period? I've tried, but don't know how to fix that.

How do you expect continue_ to become True?  For that to happen, the statements have to be inside the loop, after you have fetched a new value of c_or_nc.

You don't need continue_ at all.  Make the loop while True:, then after the final input, do if c_or_nc != 'Yes': / break.

Please condense this to a [mre]. Your code as-is contains several errors, and no reasonable answer will be able to fix all of them. [Edit] your program so it isolates the question you're trying to ask.

@TimRoberts sorry for misunderstanding, thats not what i said in my original post but some admins decided to edit out the context. I do not expect continue_ to become True, it was like 'I think i know my mistake, is it because if the answer is 'Yes' the first time continue_ becomes True period.'. I dont know, thats why im asking, but it seemed logical since outside of this scenario ('First 'Yes' second 'No') loop and the calculator worked as ive wanted.

All I'm saying is that the code above demonstrates a very common misconception among beginning programmers.  You wrote those if statements at the top to set continue_ based on the value of c_or_nc, and there's a tendency to think that it is persistent: if c_or_nc changes in the future, then continue_ will automatically reflect that change.  That's not how it works.  For  continue_ to change inside the loop, you have to run those statements AGAIN to test the new value of c_or_nc.

Fixed it for ya!
continue_ = True

while continue_ is True:
    n1 = float(input('Please, enter a number: '))
    op=input('Enter an operator (+, -, *, /, ^): ')
    n2=float(input('Enter a second number: '))
    if op == '+':
        result = n1 + n2
    print('The result is: '+str(result))
    c_or_nc=input('Do you want to continue? (Yes/No): ')
    if c_or_nc==('Yes'):
        continue_=True
    if c_or_nc==('No'):
        continue_=False
print('Alright! Have a nice day :).')

First of all:

You gotta initialize your continue_ variable to True, and then run the loop
Next, you gotta define what each operator does! Example: Above, I've told the computer to add the 2 numbers if the operator op=='+'
The check on whether or not the program should continue happens inside the loop, so that when the next round of looping is performed, the computer will check on the True/False condition!

Hope it helps!
Of course, there are other ways to do it and make it more code-efficient (e.g. using loop breaks, as the other comments have pointed out!), but I think, to provide more readability to beginners, the above code can be read more easily hehe

There is no need for if c_or_nc==('Yes'): since there is nothing to do in this case; the variable is already True. More useful would be an else: to display a warning if the response was invalid.

Thank you! I just want to ask/say few more things: It did solve the problem of the loop continuing to be True after answering 'No' after first 'Yes', but also the question 'Do you want to continue?' now only runs after the second time calculation runs, so like i run it once, run it twice and only then it asks me. I wouldve wanted the question to be asked after the first run of calculations, can i do it somehow? And yeah the rest of my calculator is outside of the loop, so i didnt define operations here, i only changed the strings, calculations run perfectly fine heehee. Thank you again.

@Lyo The code above does not behave as you describe.  It asks the "try again" question after EVERY computation.  If you're seeing other behavior, then you have other code in your file besides this.

Just for reference, here's how you can do what you want without using extra variables.
while True:
    n1 = float(input('Please, enter a number: '))
    op = input('Enter an operator (+, -, *, /, ^): ')
    n2 = float(input('Enter a second number: '))
    if op == '+':
        result = n1 + n2
    else:
        result = 0
    print('The result is:', result)
    c_or_nc = input('Do you want to continue? (Yes/No): ')
    if c_or_nc == 'No':
        break
print('Alright! Have a nice day :).')

Why did I add the "else" clause?  Because if you entered anything other than '+', your code would crash because the name result was not defined.
